# How to use the IsEnabled to disable the parts of an Expander, but not the whole thing?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, scrollviewer, expander

I have an expander with a custom template:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Row="0">
            <DockPanel>
                <ToggleButton DockPanel.Dock="Right" Template="{DynamicResource ExpanderToggle}" />
                <ContentPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Right" ContentSource="Tag" />
                <ContentPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Left" ContentSource="Header">
            </DockPanel>
        </Border>
        <Border Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="1">
            <ScrollViewer IsEnabled="True">
                <ContentPresenter IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Basically, I'm attempting to make it so that if I set the IsEnabled property to false my scrollviewer still can scroll (it stays enabled, but other parts of my control disable). Any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If [Robert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822020/wpf-how-to-use-the-isenabled-to-disable-the-parts-of-an-expander-but-not-the/7822140#7822140) doesn't work, you could always create an `AttachedProperty` called `IsContentEnabled` and bind your ContentPresenter's IsEnabled to that property.

```
<Expander local:IsContentEnabled="False" />

<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Row="0">
            <DockPanel>
                <ToggleButton DockPanel.Dock="Right" Template="{DynamicResource ExpanderToggle}" />
                <ContentPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Right" ContentSource="Tag" />
                <ContentPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Left" ContentSource="Header">
            </DockPanel>
        </Border>
        <Border Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="1">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <ContentPresenter IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding local:IsContentEnabled}" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

Give your DockPanel a name.  Then use e FindName (see http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/28/how-to-use-findname-with-a-contentcontrol/) to get at that DockPanel at runtime.  Set IsEnabled on it directly rather that on the higher level Expander control.  Do the same for your ContentPresenter if appropriate.